# Trying to group inner child list and get common records

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Below is my class :

```
public class MyData
    {
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public List<TestList> TestList { get; set; }
    }

 public class TestList
    {
        public int? TestId { get; set; }
    }
```

This above class holds below sample data (`var data = List<MyData>()`)  :

```
[o] : Region = "abc"
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100
         },
         {
           TestId : 101
         },
       ],
[1] : Region = "Pqr"
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100
         },
         {
           TestId : 101
         },
       ],
[2] : Region = "Lmn"
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100
         },
         {
           TestId : 101
         },
         {
           TestId : 102
         },
       ]
```

Below is the sample class in which I am trying to get list of tests and for each test I want list of variantsrank i.e Abc,Pq,lmn :

```
public class Test
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public List<VariantsRank> VariantsRanks { get; set; }
    }

    public class VariantsRank
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to generate final output in above class i.e `List<Test>` like below:

```
[0] :Test Id = 100
   "VariantsRanks": 
       [
         {
           Name : "abc",
           Rank : 0   
         },
         {
            Name : "Pqr",
            Rank : 1 
         },
         {
           Name : "Lmn",
           Rank :  2
         },
       ],
[1] :Test Id = 101
   "VariantsRanks": 
       [
         {
           Name : "abc",
           Rank : 0   
         },
         {
            Name : "Pqr",
            Rank : 1 
         },
         {
           Name : "Lmn",
           Rank :  2
         },
       ],
[2] :Test Id = 102
   "VariantsRanks": 
       [
         {
           Name : "lmn",
           Rank : 0   
         },
       ]
```

So this is how I am trying to generate `List<Test>` but here I don't understand that how do I group by nested TestList so that I can get common VariantsRank name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to "flatten" the nested list with `SelectMany` so that you have tuples of TestId,Region.  Then it is easy to group by TestId to get the regions in rank order.  It would look something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Test> Group(this IEnumerable<MyData> data)
{
    var pairs = data
        .SelectMany(d => d.TestList
             .Select(t => new {
                 Region = d.Region,
                 TestId: t.TestId
             })
        );

    // now group by testId
    var groups = pairs.GroupBy(pair => pair.TestId);

    // now convert each group to your Test class
    var result = groups.Select(group => new Test
        {
            TestId = pair.Key,
            VariantsRanks = group.Select((p, i) =>
               new VariantsRank { Name = p.Region, Rank = i }).ToList()
        }
    );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)